# Find cumulative number by increment in percentage in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe (new_df) as below ( sample of original)

```
structure(list(Facility = c("ABE", "ABE", "ABE", "ABE", "ABE", 
"ABE", "ABE", "ABE", "ABE", "ABE"), Year.x = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 
2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026), `Growth Rate` = c(25.375, 
15.5865736124958, 14.5677592486103, 12.3473314371758, 10.253164556962, 
6.67251975417032, 2.65906932573599, 1.55411655874191, 1.51211513936965, 
1.5853074898301), Year.y = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), OPS = c(7200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to input value in OPS such that it shows cumulative times percent increment (column Growth rate)
Below is gist of work I am trying to do

For (all facilities in OPSNET)
For each facility in OPSNET find the new number of operations for year 2017 to 2045 which is based on the growth rate of each facility for each year. Remember that growth rate is give in “GR”.

Let’s say you want to do that for facility “ABE”. First you multiply 7200 by growth rate in year 2017 (25) and sum it up with 7200 which gives you 9027. Then you multiply 9027 by growth rate in 2018 (15) and sum it up with 9027 which gives you 10434. You do that until year 2045.

I have tried below using dplyr but I am struggling how to multiple with percent increment while taking

my take :-

```
new_df <- new_df %>% arrange(Facility, Year.x) %>% 
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum(OPS))
```

Please assist me!

Comment: Use `cumprod`. For instance, `cumprod(1+df$"Growth Rate"/100)` gives you the cumulative rates you need to multiply to the initial `OPS` value.

Comment: Thanks for quick help but how would cumprod be used for each levels in facility column, could you please clear that with an example. I feel its something very little just could not figure it out

Comment: Can you post the expected result? Not sure to really understand what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(a)){
 if(a$Facility[i]==a$Facility[i-1]){
   a$OPS[i] <- (a$OPS[i-1])*((a$`Growth Rate`[i-1]/100)+1)
 }
}
```